# Fail to binding LocalDate without @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, localdate, modelattribute

I can't understand how adding `@ModelAttribute` explicitly make difference...

I added @DateTimeFormat for binding String argument to LocalDate, but without @ModelAttribute the variable `startDate` did not binded and was `null`.

The other properties are all clearly binded well, with or without @ModelAttribute!

There is no body, it's just GET request with parameters.
And I'm testing this with mock mvc, junit5, springBootTest!

```
class RequestDto {

    private int a;
    private String b;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd)
    private LocalDate startDate;

}
```

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping

    // success to binding
    @GetMapping("/simulations")
    public ResponseDto do(@ModelAttribute RequestDto requestDto) {
        ...
    }

    // fail to binding, requestDto.getDate is null!
    @GetMapping("/simulations")
    public ResponseDto do(RequestDto requestDto) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Is class @Controller or @RestController?

Comment: @user7294900 it's RestController

Comment: What are you posting a body with JSON or XML or a form to this method?

Comment: @M. Deinum There is no body, just query params

Comment: If I don't understand something, I do a quick search for some docs or links that explain it to me. Would this help you along? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation